# Is it okay to reply "Will do. Thanks."?

Tags: professionalism, communication

I recently accepted an offer to work at another location. There is a person in contact with me and they sent me a first week preparation email. I replied that I got the email and would read it over and comply and prepare with anything. They then replied thanking me that I replied and if I had any further questions or concerns to contact them. I then replied, "Will do. Thanks."

Now I'm not sure if that is considered professional? Would that be considered rude or sarcastic in any way or if I am just overreacting?

Comment: Informal, not rude. You're overreacting.

Comment: I often use the the exact same phrase in emails to my bosses. None of them have ever considered it rude or sarcastic - and they are aware of my sarcastic tendencies.

Comment: In Ireland we say "Yeah sound"

Answer (score 48):

> I then replied, "Will do. Thanks."
>
> Now I'm not sure if that is considered professional? Would that be
>   considered rude or sarcastic in any way or if I am just overreacting?

At least in the US, and in most companies, that is perfectly acceptable casual conversation and perfectly professional. It sounds neither rude nor sarcastic to my ears.

I think you are over-thinking this one. I wouldn't be worried.

Comment: It would be fine in UK and Ireland also.

Comment: And on Brazil, when using our "Vou sim/Pode deixar" forms.

Comment: What about "Acknowledged, thanks." Would that be less polite? Worked with a U.S. company where they'd say "Roger that", which seemed quirky but not bad.

Answer (score 5):

It's clear, succinct and concise. There's absolutely nothing wrong with that phrase.

Take a moment, and consider the fact that whoever is receiving the message, is just a person. Just because they're a recruiter doesn't mean they no longer understand normal human language. They've probably responded with the exact same phrase themselves on numerous occasions.

Imagine yourself in their spot, receiving that message. Would you think "hey, that's not formal enough. He's out."?

Answer (score 0):

It's considered rude or sarcastic only if you take being informal as being unprofessional. Unfortunately, I have no doubt that there are some workplaces that are uptight enough to make exactly that equivalency. You are the one who is best positioned to determine how uptight your workplace is and thus, you are the one best positioned to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

As an email answer that is fine. If you say this out loud though, it could be considered rude depending on the tone of voice and body language you use. If you sound neutral or upbeat and eager,  it is fine. If you sound annoyed it isn't. If you roll your eyes while saying it, it wil be interpreted as rude.

Answer (score 0):

I just went throught the same chain of thought and used "please" instead. The person replied with " will do". Sinse ime the begger i optes for the submisive term than the demanding one. 2cents